Can heat sinks and/or heat pipes be retrofitted onto an existing electronic device?
I have a USB hub that is going into an additional enclosure that is fairly airtight. This USB hub is only rated for 0C to 40C operational, however it will need to survive hotter and colder temperatures than that for my application. Because of the airtight nature of the enclosure fans would not be practical. I do have the ability to modify the already fabricated PCB if necessary. What are my options here? Are heat pipes or heat sinks realistic for this application if I can manage to fit them on the PCB?

If the inside of the enclosure is already going to be outside of the acceptable temperature range, then adding fans or heat pipes to anything inside it will not help.

Good point, I will turn my attention to maintaining the temperature on the outside of the enclosure in order to maintain the proper temperature range on the inside of the enclosure.

Wouldn't it be easier to find a USB hub which is rated for your temperature range?

@Sandro Ideally yes, but I have to work with an existing system that utilizes this component.

@vir Adding internal fans heat pipes etc will improve the themal conductivity of the interior. If the outside of the enclosure has a sink to dump the internal heat then this can improve things.

@DDuck if you knew what components were the limiting ones on the USB hub then in theory you could use a heat pipe to dump the heat through the enclosure but identifying the components would be a guess and the OP said nothing about any external heatsink or whether the case was thermally conductive.

How would heat sinks make it handle lower temperatures though? The components used in the design are what they are.

I guess you'd have to do a bit of reverse engineering on that hub.
Say it's a board in a small plastic enclosure. Plastic doesn't conduct heat very well, and there isn't much air convection in a tiny enclosure, especially if the board is horizontal. So thermal resistance from the thermally critical chip to outside air would be quite high.
In normal use, at maximum spec (all ports loaded at max allowed current) you could measure the temperature inside the enclosure. If it is, say 60°C, then obviously the hub would work in 60°C air by simply removing the enclosure.
But is it a good idea? Probably not when you can get a cheap -40°C-85°C rated hub or even roll your own!
On the cold temperatures side you have other problems: capacitance of ceramic caps depends on temperature... they all look the same... so how would you know if the manufacturer went "full luxury" and spent an extra tenth of a cent for X7R, or did the bean counters use Y5V or worse?... That would cause the hub chip to lose most of its decoupling capacitance at temperature extremes, cause random hard to debug issues...

Also ESR of your electrolytics will increase a lot at low temperature, which is bad news if it's a USB-C hub with a switching regulator... voltage references and clocks drift too...
